# Which one of this is efficient in mssql? Setting Default value for a bit column as 0 (or) checking for null in all queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I don't have much knowledge regarding Database. Still I have 2 cases. Need to know which one is efficient.

Say I'm going to have a checkbox for a table, whose value I'm gonna store in table and there will be millions of records in it. let us consider the column name as CHECK_RECORD.

I can do this in 2 ways.

```
Case 1: Creating CHECK_RECORD column as bit type without any default value.
```

While updating it, I shall update CHECK_RECORD=1 Where CHECK_RECORD will have Null or 0.

```
Case 2: Creating CHECK_RECORD column as bit type with 0 as default value.
```

While updating it, I shall update CHECK_RECORD=1 Where CHECK_RECORD = 0.

Need to know which one will be efficient for handling millions of data. If there is any other efficient way kindly comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most optimal solution would be to make the CHECK_RECORD column be NOT NULL and create an index on it. That would give you the best performance. Columns that allow NULL's take up extra space in the row.

If your table already has records, you will have to first create the column as NULL-able, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CHECK_RECORD BIT NULL
UPDATE mytable SET CHECK_RECORD=0
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN CHECK_RECORD BIT NOT NULL
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable (CHECK_RECORD)
```

Then when you do your update, the index will be used:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET CHECK_RECORD=1 
WHERE CHECK_RECORD=0
```

Comment: I have seen in this post that indexing on bit columns for large data will have no effect - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58939/is-adding-index-on-bit-column-significantly-slow-down-inserts. Do u recommend it still ?

Comment: @vsriram92, I would definitely use an index. If you have millions of records, I would assume that the updating process will be incremental in nature, e.g. a small percentage of the records will have CHECK_RECORD=1 as compared to records where CHECK_RECORD=0. An index will give quick access to those rows especially in this type of incremental scenario.

You can also consider using a filtered index (with a WHERE clause) starting from SQL Server 2012.

Comment: In my application there is also a option to Check all, which checks the millions of records at a stretch.

Comment: If you have a situation where you have to check millions of records at once, meaning you have to flip CHECK_RECORD to 1, do something, and flip it back to 0, then you must consider the transaction size. Doing this in one statement will result in a huge transaction in terms of size (MB-s), time (seconds/minutes) and locks that will prevent other users from access. In such a case, consider breaking it up in manageable batches, say 10000 records, each of which would be done in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The `BIT` type is a fixed width integer representing a single bit.  It can take values of `0`, `1`, or `NULL`.  But because it is fixed width, storing `NULL` in the column will still require a single bit.

So I would recommend that you just store `0` or `1` in the `BIT` column to represent the state of the checkbox.  You might have to check for `NULL` initially, unless of course you assign a default value of `0`, indicating that all checkboxes are "born" unchecked.